# Access the value after sorting using xdocument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is the code:

```
//LOADED MY XML
jobdetails.group = TM_item.Group_xml.ToString();
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(jobdetails.group); //jobdetails is a model object
var newxDoc = new XElement("Root", 
   xDoc.Root
      .Elements()
      .OrderBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"))
      .Select(n => new 
      {
            GroupName = n.Attribute("name").Value, 
            status = n.Element("Status").Value 
      })
);
xml = newxDoc.ToString();
```

Now I want to access `GroupName` and `status` and want to store that in `out` variable??
Any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no (programmer accessible) typename for an anonymous type.

So you need to define one. Or use something from the Framework:

```
void GetData(out Tuple<string, string> extracted) {
  extracted = null;

  // ...

  extracted = xDoc.Root.Elements()
                  .OrderBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"))
                  .Select(n => Tuple.Create(
                                       n.Attribute("name").Value, 
                                       n.Element("Status").Value
                  ));
               );
}
```